# Terraform: Declaring a structured/typed local or variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file, terraform-provider-cloudflare

I am implementing a Cloudflare Terraform script and I am having issues deduplicating a block for zone_settings:

```
resource "cloudflare_zone_settings_override" "my-domain-settings-1" {
  zone_id = cloudflare_zone.my_domain1.id
  settings {
    # very_long_list_of_settings
  }
}

resource "cloudflare_zone_settings_override" "my-domain-settings-2" {
  zone_id = cloudflare_zone.my_domain2.id
  settings {
    # very_long_list_of_settings
  }
}
```

The settings block has ~60 lines as is completely equal. I tried to implement this via foreach:

```
variable domains {
  default = [
    # ERROR: Variables may not be used here.
    cloudflare_zone.my_domain1,
    cloudflare_zone.my_domain2,
  ]
}

resource "cloudflare_zone_settings_override" "partners-zone-settings" {
  name = var.domains[count.index].name
  zone_id = var.domains[count.index].id
  settings {
    # very_long_list_of_settings
  }
}
```

(full code: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/ee10aa7d63adda866fe39151a9e015d9)

But this is failing with `Variables may not be used here.` within the variables block.

So I tried with locals:

```
locals {
  zone_settings {
    # very_long_list_of_settings
    # ERROR: cannot have nested blocks
  }
}

resource "cloudflare_zone_settings_override" "my-domain-settings-1" {
  zone_id = cloudflare_zone.divadlouhasicu_cz.id
  # ERROR: An argument named "settings" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "settings"?
  settings = var.zone_settings
}

resource "cloudflare_zone_settings_override" "my-domain-settings-2" {
  zone_id = cloudflare_zone.divadlouhasicu_net.id
  # ERROR: An argument named "settings" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "settings"?
  settings = var.zone_settings
}
```

(full code: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/76ff39f3baf68df19dfbd05a37eb0ea5)

But this ends with errors in the two comments above.

Is there even a way to do this?

Comment: I do not think there is a way :(

Answer (score 0):

čau Vojto,

in case you're Terraform 12 or higher you can use `for_each` construct. In lower version there is no way.

https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each

Code would look something like this (I didn't test this so some modification will be needed almost for sure):

```
variable domains {
  default = [
    # ERROR: Variables may not be used here.
    cloudflare_zone.my_domain1,
    cloudflare_zone.my_domain2,
  ]
}

resource "cloudflare_zone_settings_override" "my-domain-settings-1" {
  for_each = var.domains

  zone_id = each.value
  settings {
    # very_long_list_of_settings
  }
}
```

Comment: čau Ondřeji, unfortunately this is not going to work as the variable `domains` cannot contain other variables - the same problem like I describe above: `ERROR: Variables may not be used here`

Comment: This answer should get you in the right direction if you change the `variable domains` block to a locals block (which is how you define non-input variables), something like this:

`locals {
 domains = [cloudflare_zone.my_domain1, cloudflare_zone.my_domain2] 
   }`

And reference it with `for_each = local.domains`.

Comment: I'm just testing it and for me it doesn't work this way:

`The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type tuple.`

Comment: To overcome above error `toset()` function should be used this way:

`toset([cloudflare_zone.my_domain1.id, cloudflare_zone.my_domain2.id])` 

either in `local` or directly inside `for_each` but for whatever reasons it doesn't work for me neither:

`The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: "for_each" supports mapsand sets of strings, but you have provided a set containing type dynamic.`

I tried converting explicitly each export value with `tostring()` but without any luck. Maybe this will help you to go right direction :)

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/24049#issuecomment-583455121

Comment: maybe it's resolved in newest TF version.. I'm using 12.28 for testing